# iOS - Add Certificate to application

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

I have a private application that will communicate with web service and use client certificate authentication.

It is required that I use a different certificate for each user, so I can't add it to the application resources.
I tested the application with ipad simulator and I used a certificate located on my computer and it worked.

How can I install the application without any certificate and then after the application is installed on iPad add a certificate and read this certificate on my aplication?

I thought about sending an email with the certificate for each client, but how can the client add the certificate and how will I read it on my application?

Comment: Why don't you download the certificate programmatically to, for example, the Library directory of your application?

Comment: I would recommend something like Aquatic Prime for this, especially for unique certs.

Comment: @CodaFi - I didnt know Aquatic Prime. Thanks. But it is required by the client that I used certificates provided by him. I now just need to figure out how to send the certificates to iPad and add it the so I can use read it on my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the certificate in a server folder and call the URL in the code, like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoururl.com/cert.pem"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

With this code, the app identifies that it's a certificate and ask the user to install it (which is really simple!).

**EDIT**

When my device doesn't have the certificate installed, my url requests do not work and I get an error that I treat it with this method:

```
+ (void)treatConnectionErrors:(NSError *)error withAlert:(BOOL)withAlert
{
    if (error)
    {
        /* If it's a certificate error, shows alert with link to install certificate */
        if ([error code] == -1202)
        {
            // do something, such as show alertview warning about the certificate 
        } else {
            // treat other errors if you want to
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: If certificates will be in open (on the server), everybody can download it and use it for client authentication

Comment: Use cryptography, pass some post parameters or something like that to check which user is using the app and what certificate will be downloaded

Comment: @CainaSouza Store the certificate on server is a option. But I would like to know is if possible by sending an email.

Comment: I've just tested here with a certificate that I use in my app (extension .pem). I sent to my email, accessed the Mail app in my iPad and when I try to open the certificate attached to the email, it already redirects me to the Settings, for installing it! So it works fine in your case!

Comment: @CainaSouza I successfully add the certificate on settings using email .But how can I read it on my application?

Comment: In my app, I use the certificate for URL requests, then, when I don't have it installed, the request returns an error that I treat it (check my answer. I edited.)

Comment: @CainaSouza My idea is not use the certificate in a server folder. 
The certificates will be sent to users by email attachmentand and they will install it. The certificate is installed on iPad settings, that I can't read. Is there any way to redirect the certificate to my application folder?

Comment: What will you use the certificate for? My certificate is on the device and i'm not retrieving from the server. What I meant was that in case of url connections, if your server requires a connection that uses the certificate and you don't have it installed, then you'll get an error.

Comment: @CainaSouza I think I found the solution - https://devforums.apple.com/message/603203#603203. I will try it.